# Why is the ssh asking for password still?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have generated an rsa key pair and am using it to ssh into my server without the need of a password. The server contains the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, into which I've copied the file in my client's `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, which looks as follows:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2wqegqeweqrwqgwqet......iCA2unoYGtLgS7F8veyKl85jJwdZpwqhCXnkei4gq+ABZm7STs/7ns= foo@foo.foobar.net
```

However, upon ssh'ing as follows, I'm getting the following:

```
my-shell ~ % ssh -Yvv prikshet@proto1
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
...
...
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:AFKLy9UvmEcUzpn1Ub4aUjqVPJJL1Zri8KWDtJARXL8
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:AFKLy9UvmEcUzpn1Ub4aUjqVPJJL1Zri8KWDtJARXL8
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/prikshetsharma/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

The server is still asking for the password. The server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` permissions are the following:

```
my_shell~$ sudo ls -lah  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
[sudo] password for prikshet: 
-rw------- 1 root root 595 Sep 11 18:03 /home/prikshet/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Why is the server still asking for the password?

Comment: The `authorized_keys` should be owned by the user, not by root

Comment: The permissions should be 644.

Comment: Okay, now I have the following:
sudo ls -lah  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 595 Sep 11 18:03 /home/prikshet/.ssh/authorized_keys
It's still asking for the password upon ssh'ing, showing the same behavior

Comment: @lampbottle the owner is still root.

Comment: `sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should fix it.